# Wordpress Sort Categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress Site.
Here is my code to display the sub categories.

```
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
$catlist = wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id);

if ($catlist) {
  //Output
} else {
  //here i will display the catslist
}
```

i know, the `$catlist` is on "else" empty, whats the best way to display the "categories" of a 
subcategorie?

Find the subcategories to a categorie works great but how can i display the same result for the subcategories for the sort function?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress, belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just because it about WordPress does not mean it doesn't belong here.  There are over 30K posts relating to WordPress here.